# Unable to use File.WriteAllBytes() in asp.net MVC, cannot choose method from method group did you intend to invoke the method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I'm trying to create a copy of a file i have in my database as a byte array, I'm looking for the easiest way to do this, and on SO and everywhere else the answer seems to be:

`File.WriteAllBytes(string newfilepath, byte[] theFile);`

However I'm unable to use pretty much anything from the File class, and as soon as I type in `File.` intellisense draws a red line underneath it and says:

`cannot choose method from method group did you intend to invoke the method?`

I realise this is a very generic question, and the solution is most probably a very simple one, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Any ideas?

And here is the code where I try to create the file:

```
    var labProcessOrderLetter = from obj1 in context.LabArticles
                                join obj2 in context.ProcessLabs
                                on obj1.ProcessForLabID equals obj2.ID
                                where obj1.ID == _articleId
                                select obj2.LetterAttachment;

    byte[] thePDFLetter = (byte[]) labProcessOrderLetter.FirstOrDefault();

    var uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/_TEMP/PDF");
    var tempfilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var tempfilenameandlocation = Path.Combine(uploadPath, Path.GetFileName(tempfilename));

    File.WriteAllBytes( tempfilenameandlocation, thePDFLetter);
```

**EDIT**: Obviously I have already imported the `System.IO` namespace, and nowhere in my project I have a method or class called File, or even beginning with File.

Comment: Please show sample code, and also check you have a using directive of `using System.IO;`

Comment: Do you have property or method called File in the class that you are trying to add this? If you type File and hover over it, what information does it say in the tooltip?

Comment: @Maarten, I have no properties or methods called File in my entire application. When I type File it turns blue as it should, but when I hover over it the tooltip shows the error I posted. I already called the `System.IO` namespace in my imports, however I still get that error, using the fully qualified name as suggested by Damien seems to solve it though, really strange.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It sounds like you have a *method* that's visible to you (in the same class, say) called `File`. This will be chosen in preference to [`System.IO.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3saad2h5.aspx). So you need to fully qualify the name:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(tempfilenameandlocation, thePDFLetter);
```

(In fact, enough clues were in the question. It's [`Controller.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) that's in scope)

Comment: although, I don't have any methods called File or even beginning with File in my whole project.

Comment: If you type `File(` instead of `File.`, do you get any intellisense appearing?

Comment: No, I don't get that error when i type `File(`, in fact in the same controller I have actions returning `File()`.

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand - I asked whether you get intellisense, not an error - and, indeed, you should, since it's [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.98).aspx) method.

Comment: Yes I do get intellisene when I type File(...

Comment: Any shortcut possibility? I have many calls of `System.IO.File` methods in my controller, is there a way to omit the whole reference each time?

Comment: @Shimmy - you could introduce an alias via a [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx), e.g. `using IOFile = System.IO.File;`.

Answer (score 1):

A controller has a File already defined, for outputting files in a nice way. Just fully qualify it with System.IO.File